# Switch integer places inside a loop

Tags: java

I'm in an entry level java course attempting to manipulate a 4 digit integer. I need to add 7 to each digit, then modulus, ten, and switch the first and third, and second and fourth digits.

I'm fairly sure I'm able to manipulate the original data, but how can I switch the digits? I just can't seem to get it. Is there a way to return this, so I can reorganize it outside of the loop instead of instantly printing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the data");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char x = input.charAt(i);
        int y = Character.getNumericValue(x);
        int seven = addSeven(y);
        int mod = modulusTen(seven);
        System.out.print(mod);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
private static int addSeven(int data)
{
    int add7 = data + 7;
    return(add7);
}

private static int modulusTen(int mod)
{
    int modulusTen = mod % 10;
    return(modulusTen);
}
```

Comment: if you go for quick solution then you can manage an array of size 4 inside your main method. and place each character according to its position

Comment: No need for arrays on this one. Just use modulo 10 to find the digits and multiply it to 10, 100, 1000, ... to rearrange. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If would be easier if you used an array to hold your data

```
 int arr [] = new int [4];

 // check input is 4 in length then

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    char x = input.charAt(i);
    int y = Character.getNumericValue(x);
    int seven = addSeven(y);
    int mod = modulusTen(seven);
    arr[i] = mod;
}

// then perform your swap logic

int tmp = arr [0];
arr[0] = arr[2];
arr [2] = tmp;

tmp = arr[1];
arr[1] = arr[3];
arr[3] = tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! We haven't gotten to arrays yet, so I might get marked down, but I appreciate it.

Comment: well I guess the key point is that you need a separate variable for each index of string (that's all arrays do anyway), and the second key point is to use a temporary variable to hold data whilst you are doing the swap.